# Module .so not loaded in apk, but is built

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have a project that has an app, and a module that is a library. Both have native c++ code compiled with Cmake.

The app works fine, with all four of the native .so libraries compiling and showing up in the .apk file, but the module is being compiled (it has a .so file in \build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj), but the .so is not being moved into the .apk with the rest of the libraries. This gives me a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when I try to run any module code from the app.

Do any of you have any idea what I need to fix for the build to package the .so file from the module?

app build.gradle

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nyota"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 2
        versionName '1.0.1'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ''
            }
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.10.2'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation project(path: ':JavaRTP')
    def nav_version = "2.4.1"
    def acraVersion = '5.8.4'

    implementation "ch.acra:acra-mail:$acraVersion"
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:$acraVersion"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Feature module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
}
```

module library build.gradle:

```html
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
}



android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ''
            }
        }


    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.10.2'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

My Java class:

```
package com.active.javartp;

public class RTPPacket {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("javartp");
    }

    public RTPPacket(long handle) {
        nativeHandle = handle;
    }

    public RTPPacket(byte[] data, int size) {
        nativeHandle = nativeConstructor(data, size);
    }

    private native long nativeConstructor(byte[] data, int size);

    private long nativeHandle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call loadLibrary in your Java code to load the .so file.  Until you do that, the library is unavailable.  You also need to make sure the signatures of your Java native functions and the C JNI functions line up properly.  Failure to do either will lead to that error.  Which you didn't do I can't tell, as you didn't post your C or Java side code.

Comment: I've posted the Java class to go along with the lib. I have been using loadLibrary, but the .so lib isn't being packaged into the .apk (but it is being generated). I also have double checked that the C JNI and Java native functions do indeed line up.

Comment: Ok, if I change the build variant to 'release', the .so file shows up in the .apk. What could possibly be going on?

Comment: Is it possible your debug build is for an ABI you're not building for?  For example, release is on ARM, and debug is on x86?